# How to disable restore/resume/saved-state for a specific application in Yosemite

Tags: macos, preview

For most applications I like the OSX feature of remembering which documents were open.  But it drives me nuts in Preview.

In past versions of OSX there was a simple preference that could be altered for each application:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/177469/18486

This no longer works in Yosemite.  Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

After some playing around I found a workaround, not sure if there's something better:

1. Open Preview, close all documents, close Preview.
2. `cd ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.Preview.savedState`
3. `chmod -w .`
4. `chmod -w *`

There will be similar folders for other applications.

Answer (score -3):

As for the "similar folders" mentioned by Dalin, there are a bunch in ~/Library/Containers; but there may be another in ~/Library itself.

```
cd ~/Library
rm -rf 'Saved Application State'/*   # eliminate contents
chmod 500 'Saved Application State'  # make it read-only
```

This blocks automatic saving for other applications in this location.
You can find the other 'Saved Application State' folders as follows:

```
cd ~/Library/Containers
find . -name 'Saved *'
```

Comment: Dalin only wanted to block saved state behaviour for a *single* application; what you are suggesting would disable it for **all** applications that use the `~/Library/Saved Application State` location.